# How to push to remote using phabricator

Tags: git, phabricator

Phabricator provides endpoints for creating diff, editing diff, or searching revisions. But I could not find the endpoint for pushing a revision to remote repository, say `origin/master`. Do I have to use the basic git commands (git pull + git push) to do so?

Another related question is about `arc land`. What happens after `arc land` is called? Is it a wrapper of basic git pushing?

Comment: `origin/master` is a *remote-tracking name*, not a repository. You would generally push a commit to `origin`, which is a *remote*, which stores the URL of another repository. (I have not used `arc`.)

Comment: Oh yea my mistake. My understanding is Phabricator provides a place for holding diffs that can be reviewed/commented by colleagues. And after the review/revision the changes can be committed and then pushed into the remote repo using git commands. Please correct me if my conclusion is wrong: 1) I mistakenly messed them together. 2) Phabricator does not provide the function to push local commit to remote repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc land` does a bit more than just `git push`. It also fetches any parallel changes that were made in the remote and rebases and deletes your temporary branch after pushing.

Before that, it also potentially triggers a linter and unit tests.

After push, it also potentially triggers a CI/CD.

Some references:

https://we.phorge.it/book/phorge/article/arcanist/

https://we.phorge.it/book/phorge/article/arcanist_lint/

https://we.phorge.it/book/phorge/article/arcanist_lint_unit/